Black status bar on setting it to immersiveSticky
I tried removing the status bar on my app and the solution I found included:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
but the Problem is when I set this either in the main() or in init() of my page, both ways I see a black status bar.
I have tried the following:

setting the status bar to transparent
setting the status bar to white
instead of immersiveSticky, immersive and leanBack
changing status bar brightness and status bar icon brightness

But I face the same problem which is that if there is a notification with a black icon,
It is clearly visible on the invisible status bar
I found the problem but I dont know how to fix it.
On vivo, apps can decide to show the camera or hide it with a black strip(in my case), but I had to manually change the setting from Automatic Fitting (let app decide) to Show   the camera
I want the app to do this automatically
Example:
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {

@override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container();
}

}


Add in 'android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml'
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>

It's worked for me.
